# What is 'term_group' for 'order_by' in get_terms()?

Tags: terms

I was just reading the [Codex regarding `get_terms();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms). What exactly is the parameter `'term_group'`?

You can use it in (*example*): `'order_by'` for `get_terms();`.

*Hint: I could be all terms that share the same names, but have different slugs.*

Comment: I asked again/parallel on the wp-hackers [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de#!topic/wp-hackers/2Phxyj7Mzwo).

Comment: The bottom line is... don't use it, as it's not currently supported and term aliasing is neither currently supported either, nor is it fully thought through and has a bunch of nasty pitfalls to boot. Codex updated.

Comment: [Answer from @otto](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/term-group-column#post-835250) on `wp.org`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The idea of term groups was to have a term with multiple aliases.

This feature doesn't seem to be fully backed and is therefore practically never used.