# What is wp_insert_term "alias_of" arg for?

Tags: taxonomy, terms, slug

I currently put my hands into WP taxonomy and terms to find solutions for my project.
I knew that it's not possible to have same terms slug when creating a term with `wp_insert_term` in one Custom Taxonomy and between different Custom Taxonomies, but i would like to have different terms linked to the same url (so slugs are involved in it) and get all the related posts to these different terms.

Say a custom Taxonomy 'tax' and the following terms in it :

```
a (slug : a) 
--b (slug : b)
-c (slug : c)
---d (slug : d)
```

I can access the different tax term with the following links :

```
/tax/a
/tax/b
/tax/c
/tax/d
```

If i want to insert a term with `wp_insert_term('e','tax',array(slug=>'a')`, WP will modify the slug to 'a1' because slugs should be unique...

So, seems impossible to redirect different terms to the same slug/url and get all the custom posts from 'a' and 'e'.

And what about `alias_of` argument ? Can't find any full documentation about it . Wasn't it precisely for that kind of issue ?
I've inserted several terms with that kind of code : `wp_insert_term('e','tax',array(slug=>'e','alias_of'=>'a')` but it doesn't change anything, WP creates different unique slugs for all my entries and doesn't care about `alias_of`.

Is Anybody here can clarify this or have a solution ?

thanks a lot !

**EDIT**

Seems to be related to `term_group` , a feature that isn't really yet supported by WP. There is a `term_group` field in wp_terms [database](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Taxonomy) . The value of this field is set on term creation `wp_insert_term($name,$taxonomy,array('alias_of' => $slug)` and retrieve when get a term with (for ex `get_term_by()->term_group` function).
There should be a way to query this but with the `terms metas` support, i don't really see the interest ...

Comment: I could only find the `alias_of` implementation in the `wp_insert_term()` and `wp_update_term()` functions so I would think that this is still only half baked featured in the core.

Comment: Yeps, same for me ... but this feature would be interesting because i need a way to display all the posts related to multiple Taxonomy terms on a single url within the same slug... and by the way, make relationships between same term name in different level of the Taxonomy. I could imagine `alias_of` announce what we will be able to do in future, but when :)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/get-terms-amp-term-group-td17582.html) posting, found on the net, could help you a little to enlighten some? I am not sure but it could not harm to read imho. As it seems an interesting item which is not clearly documented.

Comment: @Charles , thanks for the link ... it seems groups and alias aren't supported yet , this [post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23169/what-is-term-group-for-order-by-in-get-terms) seems to confirm that...
Weird.. it looks too that these "on hold" features are in core for years :-/

Comment: I've edited the initial question with related searches about `term_group` and `alias_of`

Comment: I just wanted to clarify "I knew that it's not possible to have same terms slug when creating a term with wp_insert_term in one Custom Taxonomy and between different Custom Taxonomies".  It is now possible to have the same slug used in multiple taxonomies (as of version 4.2 I believe)

Answer (score 4):

In the [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/) it says:

> **'alias_of'**
>
> *(string)* Slug of the term to make this term an alias of. Default empty string. Accepts a term slug.

This makes a term an alias of another term. Using your example this is how you would use it:

```
wp_insert_term( 'e', 'tax', array( 'alias_of' => 'a' ) );
```

This would create a new term `e` in the `tax` taxonomy without its own slug, and posts in `e` would also show up under the `a` slug.

Comment: To clarify this a bit; you're saying `http://example.com/tax/e/` and `http://example.com/tax/a/` would show the same posts assigned to category `e`?

Comment: No, in my example, `http://example.com/tax/e/` would not exist, as the term `e` would not have been assigned a slug. All posts using `e` would show up in `http://example.com/tax/a/`.