# How to display taxonomy terms the way they are hierarchical

Tags: order, terms, categories

Reading [Kaiser's query and Scribu's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/23169/22728) I'm now in an ocean of no shore. I made a custom taxonomy, where I want to show the terms as per their hierarchy, like below:

```
Level 0
-- Level 1
--- Level 2
---- Level 3
--- Level 2
---- Level 3
---- Level 3
-- Level 1
--- Level 2
```

But I failed using `orderby => 'term_group'` in both `get_categories()` and `get_terms()`. Using `term_group` what I got is:

```
Level 0
-- Level 1
-- Level 1
--- Level 2
--- Level 2
--- Level 2
---- Level 3
---- Level 3
---- Level 3
```

I've checked the data, all the hierarchies are perfect, but they are not visibly working on the front-end in my code. But the following code's working when I's entering terms by my hand one by one:

```
$all_terms = get_categories( array(
                    'taxonomy'          => 'my_tax',
                    'show_count'        => true,
                    'hide_empty'        => false,
                    'orderby'           => 'term_group',
                ) );
```

But when I used an automated script, entering/migrating data, so that the level 0 enters first, then the level 1 and so on, the same code is not working. So I guess, the orderby was actually working on the IDs (and yes, actually it is).

How can I display the taxonomy terms the way they are hierarchical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using simple PHP, and with the help of my colleague Mr. Afzal. My existing query was:

```
$all_terms = get_categories( array(
                    'taxonomy'          => 'my_tax',
                    'show_count'        => true,
                    'hide_empty'        => false,
                    'orderby'           => 'term_group', //bogus :p
                ) );
```

Instead of my existing query, I made it a `$wpdb` query for a better control:

```
global $wpdb;
$tax_query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM $wpdb->terms AS t
                                        INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
                                        WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('my_tax')
                                        ORDER BY tt.parent, t.name ASC
                                    ", ARRAY_A);
```

So that we now have *alphabetically* sorted array with some valuable information that I need for further proceedings:

- `term_id`
- `parent`

#### Hierarchical Arrays

I made my tree-generating function using [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10332361/1743124), it's a recursive function:

```
function create_tax_tree( &$list, $parent ) {
    $taxTree = array();
    foreach( $parent as $ind => $val ) {
        if( isset($list[$val['term_id']]) ) {
            $val['children'] = create_tax_tree( $list, $list[$val['term_id']] );
        }
        $taxTree[] = $val;
    }
    return $taxTree;
}
```

And this function will make me an array with exact parent-child relationship. After my db Query, I did the following now:

```
if (count( $tax_query ) > 0) :

    //Making my tree array
    $taxs = array();
    foreach( $tax_query as $tax ) {
        $taxs[ $tax['parent'] ][] = $tax;
    }
    //that's my tree in array or arrays
    $tax_tree = create_tax_tree( $taxs, $taxs[0] );

else :

    _e('No term found', 'textdomain');

endif;
```

Now my tree is in `$tax_tree` variable. If I `var_dump($tax_tree)`, it's an array of arrays, which is full of exact parent-child relations.

#### Final results

To get the final result, we need another recursive function, and here PHP5 provides a [nice bunch of classes](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php), learned from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5524267). I'm using two of them in the following way:

```
$tax_iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator( $tax_tree ));

foreach( $tax_iterator as $key => $value ) {
    $depth = get_tax_depth( $term_id, true ); //custom-made function
    if( 'term_id' === $key )
        $term_id = (int) $value; //having the term_id for further use

    if( 'name' === $key ) {
        echo '<p>';
            $pad = str_repeat('---', $depth * 3); //for visual hierarchy
            echo $pad .' '. $value; //the name of the tax term
        echo '</p>';
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
Level 0
-- Level 1
--- Level 2
---- Level 3
--- Level 2
---- Level 3
---- Level 3
-- Level 1
--- Level 2
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

`term_group` seemed to have never been fully developed together with the `alias_of` parameter. What the exact indended use is (*or was*), I cannot say for sure. I would just rather avoid the use of those two parameters.

Regarding your issue of creating a hierarchical tree, [`wp_list_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) immediately jumps to mind (*remember this works for custom taxonomies as well*). You can either use `wp_list_categories()` as-is and manipulate the output through the parameters availble, or you can look at [`walk_category_tree()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/walk_category_tree/) which `wp_list_categories()` uses to build its tree. `walk_category_tree()` also use the [`Walker_Category` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_category/), so you can use this to exact fine tune what you need

There is also the option of writing your own recursive function to create your tree